# A search engine for images matching a Convolutional Neural Network classifier / model

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've made a simple program with keras that looks at pictures of cats and dogs, and tells you which ones are cats and which ones are dogs. What i want to do now is use the model or classifier in an image search engine and get results just for images of dogs. I understand I would have to retrain the classifier to differentiate between pictures of dogs, and pictures that are not of dogs.

Every link I find online for this just explains how to write reverse image searches, which is not what I want. I do not want to pass in an input image after the model is completed. I want to find pictures that are similar to the whole dataset.

A reverse image search that reads multiple images, however, may work. Like say you could pass in 20-100 images or so, and it finds images that are similar all(or almost all) of the passed in images.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I didn't understand it exactly. You want to take a group of images and categorize them?

Comment: @Meisam No I want to create a model that can identify dog images. Then I want to search the internet for images which the model identifies as a dog. It's kind of like a reverse image search, but I think it'll be more accurate because it's a model trained on a large number of similar images, so it returns images which the model identifies as correct, instead of finding images that are similar to just one image. I want to search the internet for images that I don't already have though. Essentially it would be a way to increase my dataset.